# A question on a result of Imre Ruzsa concerning sum-sets

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, additive-combinatorics

Th main result of [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.04146.pdf) of Imre Ruzsa implies the following

> **Corollary (Ruzsa):** For every $r\in\mathbb N$ there exists a real number $\alpha<1$ and a positive integer $m$ such that for every integer $q\ge m$ the cyclic group $C_q$ of order $q$ contains a subset $A$ such that $A-A=C_q$ but the sum-set $A^{+r}:=\{x_1+\dots+x_r:x_1,\dots,x_r\in A\}$ has cardinality $|A^{+r}|<q^\alpha<|C_q|$.

On the other hand, [Nathanson](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03015.pdf) citing the result of Ruzsa mentions only a weaker version of the above corollary, which was proved earlier by [Haight](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematika/article/difference-covers-which-have-small-ksums-for-any-k/1BB761A59D927E743FA96D666EC2BBF6):

> **Theorem (Haight):** For every $r\in\mathbb N$ there exists a finite cyclic group $G$ containing a subset $A\subset G$ such that $A-A=G$ and $A^{+r}\ne G$.

At the end of his [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03015.pdf), Nathanson asks the following

> **Problem (Nathanson):** Let $r$ be a positive integer and $\varepsilon>0$. Is there a cyclic group $G$ of prime order and a set $A\subset G$ such that $A-A=G$ and $|A^{+r}|<\varepsilon |G|$? Do such sets exist for all
>   cyclic group of sufficiently large prime cardinality?

It seems that the mentioned Corollary of Ruzsa answers this question of Nathanson. So, why then Nathanson asked this question? And why the preprint of Ruzsa (of 2016) is still unpublished? I would like to apply it for constructing some pathological subsemigroups in products of cyclic groups.

For me it would be sufficient to have the following weaker version of Ruzsa's Corollary:

> **Theorem (or still a Conjecture?):** For every $r\in\mathbb N$ there exists a positive integer $m$ such that for every integer $q\ge m$ the cyclic group $C_q$ of order $q$ contains a subset $A$ such that $A-A=C_q$ but  $A^{+r}\ne C_q$.

So, is the above theorem true and can I refer to the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.04146.pdf) of Ruzsa for its proof? Or there is a gap somewhere? Please help!

---

**Added in Edit.** Theorem 1 of [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/TAN_1984-1985__1__A11_0.pdf) of Haight shows that the last Theorem is true (so is not a conjecture anymore) and the answer to the question of Nathanson also is affirmative.

Comment: His name is Ruzsa, not Rusza. He is very friendly, by the way, just send him an email!

Comment: @GHfromMO Thank you! I was surprized why I cannot find his publications (writing Rusza instead of Ruzsa) on Mrlookup, but Google search was so clever that understood what I had in mind :)

Comment: Nathanson's reading of Ruzsa's result (the corollary) appears to be "there is a $q$" rather than "for sufficiently large $q$". I don't know why. But he (Nathanson) would also probably be happy to explain via email.

Comment: @GabeConant Thank you for the suggestion. I have written to both Ruzsa and Nathanson and hope to have some info soon.